# How to define multiple operators using macros

Tags: c++

I'm going to use a single macro to set the `==`, `! =`, `>`, `>=`, etc. for an array in one macro.

```cpp
#define COMPARE(operator, function)                                         \ 
    template <typename T>                                                   \
    void function(T *compArrayA, T *compArrayB, bool *resArray, int size) { \
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i ) {                                  \
            resArray[idx] = (compArrayA[idx] ## operator compArrayB[idx]);  \
        }                                                                   \
    }                                                                       \

COMPARE(==, eq);
COMPARE(!=, nq);
COMPARE(>=, greater_eq);
```

I wrote the code as above.
This code gave me the following error.

```
error: "#" not expected here
```

How can I modify it to define different operators using macros?

Comment: '##' why are you even adding these in the code? It should work fine without them

Comment: Note that `i <= size` should almost certainly be `i < size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator` is a C++ keyword. Avoid using it to avoid compilation issues. Standard practice is to use full caps for all the macro arguments; e.g.

```
#define COMPARE(OPERATOR, FUNCTION) \ ...
```

Moreover, here the `##` part is unwanted, since there is no string concatenation happening in your code. Simply use `OPERATOR` argument as it is.